# Change Plesk 12 admin e-mail

Tags: linux, windows, email, admin, plesk

This may sound a really stupid question but is it possible to change admin e-mail on plesk 12 panel? If it is can someone explain to me how?

I have changed contact info in Profile&Preferences but it seems it didn't work.

Why would i want to change it? Cause i keep getting plesk notifications on wrong e-mail. For instance i want to stop getting folowing e-mails on windows:

> Running task: C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\admin\bin\php.exe -q -dauto_prepend_file="" -c php.ini "C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\admin\plib\DailyMaintainance\script.php

Or this one from linux server:

> Backup task finished on host blabla.com.
>
> Task was created by server blabla with guid (d1febac2-????-4190-8d96-e7f7c%&?*)
>
> Creation date is: 2015-Jul-04 01:59:02
>   Task status is: warnings
>
> Dump full name is: BLA_backup_info_1507040159.xml

Any other way to disable these notifications or must i change admin e-mail?

Answer (score 1):

Just run

plesk bin init_conf -u -email user@domain.com

Comment: Ty that works. Cant give you points cause i have no permissions yet sorry.